# AnyVal use in Props(classOf[ValueActor], args...) supported?

Tags: scala, akka

I read in the following page that AnyVal is not supported for creating workers with `Props(classOf[ValueActor], args...)`. However, if I pass an `Int` then it works perfectly fine. Isn't `Int` also an `AnyVal`

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/actors.html#Edge_cases

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, Props}
case class MyValueClass(v: Int) extends AnyVal

object TestAnyVal  extends  App {
  class IntActor(value: Int) extends Actor {
    def receive = {
      case multiplier: Long => sender() ! (value * multiplier)
    }
  }
  class ValueActor(value: Int) extends Actor {
    def receive = {
      case multiplier: Long => sender() ! (value * multiplier)
    }
  }
  val valueClassProp1 = Props(classOf[IntActor], 5);
  val valueClassProp = Props(classOf[ValueActor], MyValueClass(5))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Int`, the type is `Int` both in runtime and compile time.  However, for `MyValueClass`, the type is `MyValueClass` in compile time but is `Int` in runtime (see http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html).

I believe this will work:

```
  class ValueActor(value: MyValueClass) extends Actor {
    ...
  }

  val valueClassProp = Props(new ValueActor(MyValueClass(5)))
```

or, following the [recommended best practices](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/actors.html#Recommended_Practices):

```
  class ValueActor(value: MyValueClass) extends Actor {
    ...
  }
  object ValueActor {
    def props(value: MyValueClass) = Props(new ValueActor(value))  
  }
```